# Python write function saves dataframe.__repr__ output but truncated?

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe

I have a dataframe output as a result of running some code, like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "i": self.direct_hit_i,
    "domain name": self.domain_list,
    "j": self.direct_hit_j,
    "domain name 2": self.domain_list2,
    "domain name cleaned": self.clean_domain_list,
    "domain name cleaned 2": self.clean_domain_list2
})
```

All I was really looking for was a way to save these data to whatever file e.g. txt, csv but in a way where the columns of data align with the header. I was using `df.to_csv()` with `\t` delimeter but due to the data have different lengths of string and numbers, the elements within each row never quite line up as a column with the corresponding header. So I resulted to using

```
with open('./filename.txt', 'w') as fo:
   fo.write(df.__repr__())
```

But bear in mind the data in the dataframe are lists with really long length. So for small lengths it returns

[image]

which is exactly what I want. However, when I have very big lists it gives me

[image]

So as seen below the outputs are truncated. I would like it to not be truncated since I'll need to manually scroll down and verify things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the syntax:

```
with open('./filename.txt', 'w') as fo:
   fo.write(f'{df!r}')
```

Another way of doing this export to csv would be to use a too like [Mito](https://trymito.io/so), which full disclosure I'm the author of. It should allow you to export ot CSV easier than the process here!

Comment: Unfortunately with your method the output csv file is still truncated like before. I'm giving up on csv and gonna just use excel instead. Thanks for trying though!